# Start Analysis Services on a Server remotely from local machine

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need to start Analysis Services on a Server remotely from my local machine.

I also want to make it a Batch command.

Remote Server: sqgdbfhhs001.
Analysis Service: MSSQLServerOLAPService.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
IRK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. :)

Step 1) Enter the below text in a notepad and save it as .bat file

PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"

sc \sqgdbfhhs001 stop "MSSQLServerOLAPService"
sc \sqgdbfhhs001 start "MSSQLServerOLAPService"

Step 2) Create a shortcut of the .bat file.
Step 3) Right Click on Properties of the shortcut, click on Advanced and click on RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR checkbox.

Thanks,
IRK